# How to split a string and convert it to an array of doubles

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have text like this:

```
const string geometryText = "POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)";
```

I want to get numeric values as a double array:

```
string[] lineStrings = geometryText.Split('(', ')')[1].Split(' ');

double[] lines = Array.ConvertAll(lineStrings, Convert.ToDouble);
```

This returns an array but values are not valid, it returns :

`-71064544.0` and `4228787.0`

How can I get this to work? Regex?

Comment: This code works as is: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wj2riU

Comment: Check your regional settings. I think you have another character as decimal separator.

Comment: @Dmitry is likely correct, I switched the periods to commas and got these values.

Comment: Just a side note: Why are you splitting on the parentheses? If your text is always `POINT(xxx yyy)`, then it is more efficient to trim those fixed parts using `substring()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem may be that the periods are interpreted as thousands separators instead of decimal separators.  If you want to ensure that periods are always interpreted as decimal points regardless of the machine culture use `double.Parse` with a specified culture:

```
double[] lines = lineStrings.Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use invariant culture when converting to double, different cultures will parse numbers differently based on what commas and periods mean in that culture, some cultures use . as a group seperator for example.

```
double[] lines = Array.ConvertAll(lineStrings, i => Convert.ToDouble(i, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

It works here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/UEjFaH